# Easier way to spread as inner_join a data frame on two categorical values

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
structure(list(x = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 1, 2, 3, 3, 
4, 4, 5), cat = c("type1", "type1", "type1", "type1", "type1", 
"type1", "type1", "type1", "type1", "type1", "type2", "type2", 
"type2", "type2", "type2", "type2", "type2"), y = c("a", "b", 
"a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "c", "c", "d", "c", 
"d", "c")), row.names = c(NA, 17L), .Names = c("x", "cat", "y"
), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to get this output:

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(filter(df, cat == 'type1'), filter(df, cat == 'type2'), by = 'x')
   x cat.x y.x cat.y y.y
1  1 type1   a type2   c
2  1 type1   b type2   c
3  2 type1   a type2   c
4  2 type1   b type2   c
5  3 type1   a type2   c
6  3 type1   a type2   d
7  3 type1   b type2   c
8  3 type1   b type2   d
9  4 type1   a type2   c
10 4 type1   a type2   d
11 4 type1   b type2   c
12 4 type1   b type2   d
13 5 type1   a type2   c
14 5 type1   b type2   c
```

While I get what I want, I just don't like the complex steps. I know `tidyr` package's `spread` won't work in this case. Any ideas?

Comment: That's an unusual format you want to create. I don't know what you want to do with it but in many cases the long format of your original data will be much easier to work with (because it's in a "tidy" format)

Comment: I am new to this data. I agree. Although, in this case, it seems like there is a 'filling' and pairing going on. For each `y` in type1, there is a corresponding `type2` paired row. In original data, these are missing so to speak.

Comment: It seems to me that you are only creating redundant data. In the original data, type1 and type2 are already linked via "x". Perhaps it will help if you describe what you want to do with the expected output

Comment: Got to inspect the rest of the code someone else wrote. There is really no purpose to getting the data in the above wide format as you said. Very nice! I never had to do something like this before and was wondering if I am lacking something. Thank you!